# How can i style the scroll indicator in react native scrollbar

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview

I want to add some style to the my scroll indicator in vertical scrollbar use in react native.I want to make the scroll indicator more wider than default size so that the user will clearly see the scroll indicator. As well as i want to change the colors and some other stuffs in scroll indicator.

How can i do so. is it possible to stlye the scroll indicator in vertical scroll view in react native..

Should be compatible in any platform too

Answer (score 21):

you should add Listener on scroll then create a custom view and transform it due to scrollListener and invisible scroll indicator this is simple implementation of what you want:

```
class CustomScrollview extends PureComponent {
    state = {
        indicator: new Animated.Value(0),
        wholeHeight: 1,
        visibleHeight: 0
    }
    render() {
        const indicatorSize = this.state.wholeHeight > this.state.visibleHeight ?
            this.state.visibleHeight * this.state.visibleHeight / this.state.wholeHeight :
            this.state.visibleHeight

        const difference = this.state.visibleHeight > indicatorSize ? this.state.visibleHeight - indicatorSize : 1
        return (
            <View >
                <ScrollView
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    onContentSizeChange={(width, height) => {
                        this.setState({ wholeHeight: height })
                    }}
                    onLayout={({ nativeEvent: { layout: { x, y, width, height } } }) => this.setState({ visibleHeight: height })}
                    scrollEventThrottle={16}
                    onScroll={Animated.event(
                        [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.indicator } } }]
                    )}>


                </ScrollView >
                <View style={styles.indicatorWrapper} />
                <Animated.View style={[
                    styles.indicator, {
                        height: indicatorSize,
                        transform: [{
                            translateY: Animated.multiply(this.state.indicator, this.state.visibleHeight / this.state.wholeHeight).interpolate({
                                inputRange: [0, difference],
                                outputRange: [0, difference],
                                extrapolate: 'clamp'
                            })
                        }]
                    }]} />

            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

hope this help!

Comment: @MosoAkinyemi I’m glad that you liked it :)

Comment: @LordPooria really amazing solution. Worked for me.
I only had to add bit of styling to properly position the custom scrollbar. Thank you :)

Comment: @LordPooria what to do if the flatlist is inverted?

Comment: hi, I can't see the styles definition, can you extend the code with that?

Comment: This is a very smart solution. @LordPooria, I have expanded your solution into a [customizable scroll indicator package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fanchenbao/react-native-scroll-indicator).

Answer (score 9):

You can use `indicatorStyle` props of ScrollView for change color, but it supports only three color white, black or default. You can set insets of the indicator using `scrollIndicatorInsets` props. For more custom style you can use [react-native-scroll-indicator](https://github.com/InTeach/react-native-scroll-indicator).

Comment: note to posterity: [indicatorStyle](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#indicatorstyle) is IOS only

Comment: Any solution for android ?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Animated from react-native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated), [onLayout](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#onlayout), [onContentSizeChange](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#oncontentsizechange), and [onScroll](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#onscroll) from ScrollView, and some math to accomplish this.

Basically, you can compare what is the visible height of the ScrollView, with the actual complete size of the content (visible and hidden), so there you know the scroll bar height. Then you just have to update the position of that bar when the user scrolls.

See the following code sample with react hooks:

```
const CustomScrollBarComponent = () => {
  const [completeScrollBarHeight, setCompleteScrollBarHeight] = useState(1);
  const [visibleScrollBarHeight, setVisibleScrollBarHeight] = useState(0);
  const scrollIndicator = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const scrollIndicatorSize =
    completeScrollBarHeight > visibleScrollBarHeight
      ? (visibleScrollBarHeight * visibleScrollBarHeight)
        / completeScrollBarHeight
      : visibleScrollBarHeight;

  const difference =
    visibleScrollBarHeight > scrollIndicatorSize
      ? visibleScrollBarHeight - scrollIndicatorSize
      : 1;

  const scrollIndicatorPosition = Animated.multiply(
    scrollIndicator,
    visibleScrollBarHeight / completeScrollBarHeight,
  ).interpolate({
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
    inputRange: [0, difference],
    outputRange: [0, difference],
  });

  const onContentSizeChange = (_, contentHeight) => 
    setCompleteScrollBarHeight(contentHeight);

  const onLayout = ({
    nativeEvent: {
      layout: { height },
    },
  }) => {
    setVisibleScrollBarHeight(height);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.scrollContainer}>
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingRight: 14 }}
        onContentSizeChange={onContentSizeChange}
        onLayout={onLayout}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollIndicator } } }],
          { useNativeDriver: false },
        )}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={styles.scrollViewContainer}
      >
        {/* Your ScrollView content here */}
      </ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.customScrollBarBackground}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.customScrollBar,
            {
              height: scrollIndicatorSize,
              transform: [{ translateY: scrollIndicatorPosition }],
            },
          ]}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

The styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%',
  },
  scrollViewContainer: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  customScrollBar: {
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
    borderRadius: 3,
    width: 6,
  },
  customScrollBarBackground: {
    backgroundColor: '#232323',
    borderRadius: 3,
    height: '100%',
    width: 6,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you!
Pay attention that container ("scrollContainer" style from authors's code) for custom vertical scroll indicator should be "row":)) and for horizontal - "column".

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I expanded [Lord Pooria's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57839837/9723036) and turn it into an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fanchenbao/react-native-scroll-indicator).

[**Try it on Snack Expo**](https://snack.expo.dev/@fanchenbao/react-native-scroll-indicator_demo)

### Demo

This is a simple demo copied from the package's documentation.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {ScrollViewIndicator} from '@fanchenbao/react-native-scroll-indicator';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
      <View
        style={{
          height: '30%',
          width: '80%',
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'black',
        }}>
        <ScrollViewIndicator indStyle={{backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
          <View>
            <Text>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam
              rhoncus nisl egestas, auctor mi pulvinar, aliquam metus. Nunc
              porttitor quam molestie tempor laoreet. Sed vitae ex vitae turpis
              convallis accumsan. Fusce consequat quis nisi sed lacinia. Nullam
              quis condimentum tellus. Donec ornare quam sit amet tempor
              imperdiet. Proin condimentum leo quis ipsum pretium ornare
              facilisis eget nunc. Pellentesque orci purus, pellentesque et nisl
              at, varius molestie nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus
              orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Nam ante nulla,
              sagittis vitae ante id, dignissim vestibulum ligula. Mauris
              iaculis nisi sed sapien finibus, sed pharetra risus rutrum. Cras
              laoreet mattis egestas. Pellentesque feugiat accumsan ultricies.
              Nullam viverra sapien nec tellus commodo aliquet. Integer faucibus
              quam sed nibh congue, at cursus risus vulputate. Morbi commodo
              mollis tempus.
            </Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollViewIndicator>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Fanchen but on web platform  it is unable to scroll when it's clicked on ?is it possible?

Comment: It is a known defect and an issue has been raised on it. I feel it is possible, but didn't have the bandwidth to fix it at the moment.