# Is it possible to change scrollbar color in react native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, scrollbar, react-native-scrollview

Can I create custom scrollbar look like this pic in react native.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i style the scroll indicator in react native scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50754284/how-can-i-style-the-scroll-indicator-in-react-native-scrollbar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
use this package
[react-native-scroll-indicator](https://github.com/mishabelokon/react-native-scroll-indicator#readme)

Here my code

```js
<ScrollViewIndicator
    shouldIndicatorHide={false}
    flexibleIndicator={false}
    scrollIndicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'pink' }}
    scrollIndicatorContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)' }}
>
    ...
</ScrollViewIndicator>
```

> It only supports ScrollView right now. But in the next version, it should support FlatList.