# How to hide scrollbar in expo web React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, react-native-web

How can I remove or style scrollbar in the expo app. When I apply overflow: scroll I get scrollbar both vertically and horizontally, I would like to remove horizontal scrollbar and style the vertical one. I use FlatList so I have tried to set the props like so

```
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
```

but with no effect on the web. Is it possible to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Styling in react native for Mobiles and Web is a bit different and they use different engines to render your styles. So, you should not compare them with each other. My advice is you go on and design your app with emulator or your phone. Otherwise , your going to face these kind of problems a lot and also I dont think that you can customize your apps scrollbar in web.
Although ,You can customize your scrollbar in mobile rendering
[check this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50754284/how-can-i-style-the-scroll-indicator-in-react-native-scrollbar)